# rest-client in ruby on rails -multiple request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asp.net-web-api, rest-client

I'm trying to build a web api in ruby on rails, I'm using rest-client gem.
I have tried this code in order to get a response from multiple urls and display the responses together

```
 def index
   url =  (['http://example1','https://example2'])
   url.split(",")
   i = 0
  url.each do |i|
       render json: JSON.parse(RestClient::Request.execute( method: :get, url: url[i])), layout: nil
       end
    end
 end
```

but i get an error message `"no implicit conversion of String into Integer"`

Comment: I'm thinking of a more simple approach. If you define response as an empty array like this: response = [ ] and url would be this: urls = ['http://example1','https://example2']. Then if you do: urls.each do |url| response << RestClient.get(url) end. you would already have the responses together right? After that you can do what you want with it.

Comment: you've got a lot of bugs in there.  if you say `url.each do |i|`, then in each iteration of the `each` loop, your `i` variable will be the url string `'http://example1`, etc, not an integer like you're expecting.  second, you can't call `render` multiple times in a controller.  it will throw an error.  you have to make the two requests, then combine them however you like, then render one json response.

Comment: Thanks, I did :                                                                                              urls = Base64.decode64(params[:urls]).split(',')
      response=[]
      urls.each do |url|
        result = JSON.parse(RestClient::Request.execute( method: :get, url: url))

        response.push result
      end

      render json: response, layout: nil
    end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming from this line, rather than `url[i]`, use just `i`, as i is the url you are trying to access, as an example, to deal with the implicit conversion:

```
render json: JSON.parse(RestClient::Request.execute( method: :get, url: i)), layout: nil
```

But the core issue is rendering multiple times, this can be solved by getting the data you need first, and then render the array once at the end.

Like so:

```
def index
   url_list = ['http://example1','https://example2']
   responses = []
   url_list.each do |url|
       responses << JSON.parse(RestClient::Request.execute( method: :get, url: url))
   end
   render json: responses, layout: nil
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work because there is no option to do more than  1 render, i did as described  above. thanks anyway!

Comment: The edited response above should solve this problem.